# Не выходит создать стиль Android

Tags: android

При попытке создать стиль через:

```
<style name="myTheme"
parent="Theme.Dialog"></style>
```

Выскакивает ошибка:

> error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Dialog'.

Почему оно не видит стандартные темы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо добавить `@android:style/` перед именем темы, т.е. в итоге должно быть так:

```
<style name="myTheme"
    parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"></style>
```